# Charge pump vs. boost converter for high current LED driver

Tags: batteries, boost, led-driver, charge-pump

I am designing a high current LED driver circuit to power a matrix of pulsed IR LEDs.  The LEDs will operate at 5A; 4.6V; 0.1ms pulses (~10 pulses at this frequency, wait 300s, repeat.)  The device is powered off a 3.3V Li-Po battery.

In order to deliver sufficient power, I need a DC-DC converter as part of my driver circuit.  I would have assumed that a boost converter would be a no-brainer for this application, however doing some reading seems to suggest that for such high-current applications, the size of properly rated inductors would start to become prohibitive, and so I am wondering if it is worth looking at charge pumps instead.

I've done some reading on it (https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/tutorials/7/725.html) and while the losses would be much higher than a boost converter, would the size and cost savings be significant enough to support the use of a simpler charge pump?  Are there any drawbacks from a charge pump that makes it unusable for a battery-powered device?

Comment: Isn't this article exactly what you are looking for: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/design/technical-documents/app-notes/3/3243.html ?

Comment: IR LEDs usually don't have 4.6V forward voltage... Can you rewire your IR LEDs to have Vf lower than battery voltage?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Hmm that is useful, however that is at much lower current than my application.  Still insightful however, will take that into account!

Comment: @peufeu No can do, the LED in question typically operates at a much lower voltage but for my application we need maximum radiant power (Page 2 on this datasheet https://www.vishay.com/docs/84249/vsmy99445ds.pdf)

Comment: "losses would be much higher" Seems like a pretty big drawback for a battery-powered device. "the size of properly rated inductors would start to become prohibitive" I think you have this backwards. The biggest drawback of capacitive switching compared to inductive switching is their limited current capability. I've never seen capacitive converters of greater than 60mA, whereas you can easily find inductive converters in the tens of amps, and far higher than that can be found. Remember, higher losses tends to mean everything has to be bigger for the same power to handle the inefficiency & heat

Comment: How sharp do you want the rise/fall of current to be in the LED? Got an idea of the pulse shape you want? (rise time, fall time, and flatness of the top?) If you want low current ripple or very fast rise time this will be important to design the driver. Here's an example for a very quick pulse: https://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/led-driver-for-high-power-machine-vision-flash.html

Comment: Also if the IR pulse has to be synchronized to an external trigger, think about the delay. A boost converter has to charge up the current in the inductor which adds a delay before it starts lighting the LED. If you want it triggered from a signal without latency, then you can't use that, instead you need to charge a cap with a boost converter and keep a constant voltage on it, and use something like a FET to switch the LED on.

Comment: What is the period between pulses in the bracket of 10?

Comment: What did you do? How did it work? How long between pulses in a "bracket"?

Answer (score 1):

You do not say how long between pulses in your bracket of 10 x 0.1 ms pulses - this may alter the solution (slightly easier)

Your peak power is P = I x V = 5A x 4.6V = 23 Watts.
This is not an overly demanding boost converter requirement, but even that is not essential.
Your **mean** power is
ton/tcycle x Pmax = 0.001/300 x 23W  = < 0.1 mW = tiny.

As long as you can store enough energy to provide the LED during pulsing you can recharge it at leisure.

If using a capacitor as a direct to LED store then the allowed voltage droop sets the capacitor size.
C = t x i / V
t - pulse time total, i current, V allowed voltage droop

For 0.1V allowed capacitor droop - C = (0.0001 x 10) x 5A / 0.1V = 50 mF (50,000 uF)
If you allow 1V droop then 5000 uF suffices.

If you follow the capacitor with a 5A LDO (low dropout regulator) with say 6V into LDO then a say 10,000 uF capacitor would allow zero output droop.

---

**Supercapacitor:**

Charged to 4.6V this 3.5F supercapacitor will drive the LED directly without an LDO being needed. Wiring drop is liable to be more than capacitor droop over 10 pulses.

This $US3.94/1 3.5F capacitor will supply the LED with 'nary a ripple' (OK - maybe 2 mV droop over 10 pulses). It will take a few minutes to charge intially with a 5V x 0.1A  supply and thereafter recycle after each pulse train in well under a second. A 5V x 1A inverter will shorten the initial charge accoringly.

[DGH355Q5R5](https://www.digikey.com/products/en?keywords=355q5r5)  3.5F supercapacitor.  Pricing page.
[Shortform datasheet](https://www.illinoiscapacitor.com/ic_search/super_products_detail.aspx?icpartnumber=700231)
[This](https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/illinois-capacitor/DGH155Q5R5/1572-1772-ND/7387513) 1.5F part is notionally outside its Imax spec BUT as that is for 1s your 1 ms requirement may not phase it. Or may.
It's hardly any cheaper - the 3.5F part is more attractive.

Comment: So, how should the 3.5F supercap be charged from the 3.3V Li-Po for the 10x0.1s 4.6V 5A  output?

Comment: @MicroservicesOnDDD The question assumes a boost converter - with the main discussion being between capacitor or inductor converter.

Comment: So you're suggesting a boost converter using a supercapacitor?  Like one of the chip solutions, and the flying capacitor is a supercap?